# Magento Product Price Format

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

Kindly i need to know how you want the `price` to be written exactly: **as exemple;**  if i have a `price` should i write it as `14.545,45`?

**Note:** i want to add this format of price in product admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

With floating point and no thousands separator, i.e.

```
14545.45
```

This way Magento/PHP can parse it as a floating point number and do calculations with it.

It is not how the price will be displayed, that's what the localized output formatting is doing. So on the frontend you might see

```
₹ 14.545,45
```

But that is not how you enter prices.